# Sum last values of each column issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app to sum the last values of each column but i'm getting the total sum

Here my tables

```
|policies|
 |id|  |num_policy|
   1      1234
   2      4567 

|insurances|
 |id|  |id_policy| |net_insurance| 
  1          1      4000
  2          1      6000
  3          2      3000 
  4          2      7000
```

I'm trying to do in excel

```
|id|   |num_policy|   |net_insurance|
 1        1234           4000
 2        4567           7000

          sum =        11000
```

This is my controller

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print

      @policies= Policy.find(:all)
      @dolar = Insurance.sum(:net_insurance)

      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.xls { send_data render_to_string(:partial=>"report_by_sum"),  :filename => "Report_#{Date.today}.xls" }
      end

    end
end
```

This is my model

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurances
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
  has_many :insurance_financing_details
end
```

This is my view showing the last insurance of each policy

```
<% @policies.each do |policy| %>
    <%= policy.num_policy %>
    <% policy.insurances.last(1).each do |insurance| %>          
        <%= insurance.net_insurance %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Export Excel",{:controller=>"policy",:action=>"generate_print" ,:format=>"xls"}  %>
```

This is my partial view that i'm trying to sum it should show "11000" but i got "20000"

```
 #   _report_by_sum.erb
<%= @dolar %>
```

Someone can help me with this issue please?

I will really appreciate help

Comment: Where is `@sum` being assigned in your controller?

Comment: You have multiple insurances pointing on the same policy_id, but you display only the first insurance "net amount"

Comment: @MrYoshiji my app is taking the last value....but in the controller the sum is total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
@dolar = Insurance.sum(:net_insurance)
```

Calculates the sum of all insurance entries, i.e. 4000 + 6000 + 3000 + 7000.

You have to fetch the last insurance for each policy instead:

```
@dolar = @policies.to_a.sum { |policy| policy.insurances.last.net_insurance }
```

Comment: I have a question Stefan , your code is on the view or controller?

Comment: It goes into the controller, instead of your line.

Comment: Thanks it worked but i have a final question maybe i need to post i'm trying something like this: 

@dolares = Insurance.to_a.sum  { |i| i.last.net_insurance,:joins=>:policy, :conditions=>['policies.type_money = 1  AND policies.deleted = 0   ]) }

Comment: Please post a separate question and provide more details.